# Cloudant Search Indexing boolean coming back as a string

Tags: couchdb, cloudant, couchdb-mango

I have a search index named `_design/filters` in Cloudant that has the following:

```
index("active", doc.active, {"store": true, "index": false });
```

My document looks like this:

```
{ "_id": "12345", "active": false }
```

When I do a retrieval I get the `active` property as a string and not a boolean. Is there a way I can make it so it returns a boolean?

Comment: Just to test, I created a sample doc in CouchDB 2.1.1 with a Boolean key/value. When I do a GET request with curl, I receive the document like this: `{"_id":"doc13","_rev":"2-862bb5c8c94c4a520c435ab8037cf6ff","name":"John","title":"Geek","cool":true}` In my case the Boolean value is NOT returned as string but as a true boolean

Comment: Thanks for the double check. Did you by chance check in Cloudant? as it might be a cloudant specific issue @user3405291

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect a boolean as well.

If the document you've shown here is just one example among many currently in your database, then it's possible there's a single document elsewhere in their database where `active: "false"` exists.